# How to include *type* by default when I open nautilus

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I often want to sort the elements in a folder by *type*. Yet, every time I first have to go and include *type* as column, and then sort by type. The result is tedious.
I tried going to the preference menu in Nautilus, but I did not solve my problem.

What can I do to include *type* by default when I open each and every folder in Nautilus?